# Sorting based on previous Matrix arrangement in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix of 130 x 48 called originalMatrix that are broken up into 100 x 48 rows as "weekdayTimeRows" and 30 x 48 rows as weekendTimeRows.

I am extracting 10 rows from "weekdayTimeRows" based on a logic array called "holidayLogicArray" that returns 1 for the 10 rows i want to extract and 0 for other 90 rows. These 10 rows are based on HolidayArrayDate.

I arrange them as an empty set, and then add them to a different matrix called weekendTimeRows.

```
holidayLogicArray=ismember(weekdayTimeRows(:,1),HolidayArrayDate);
holidayTimeRows=weekdayTimeRows(holidayLogicArray,:);
weekdayTimeRows(holidayLogicArray,:)=[];
weekendTimeRows=[weekendTimeRows; holidayTimeRows];
```

At this point, weekendTimeRows has its 30 rows and then the new 10 rows under it making it 40 x 48 rows. I need to sort the new 10 rows so that they fill in the same sequence of a the ORIGINAL matrix.

Example: Row 1 of 10 in holidayTimeRows is row 15 in orignalMatrix which is between rows 3 and 4 in weekendTimeRows now, so row 1 of 10 will be inserted between rows 3 and 4 instead of row 31.

NOTE: Time is random from values 1 to 130. They are NOT is ascending order. [so i cant use "sort" function]

Comment: The best solution would be to have a 'weekendLogicArray' similar to your 'holidayLogicArray' and use both to select your weekend or holiday data (using an 'or' to connect both)

Comment: Hey if you are still stuck with your problem pls update your question with an example of your data: e.g. The first 3 columns of your rows 3,4 (weekend) and 1 of holiday. To show us how you want them to be merged.